# Why no see by screen one in c++ if i am using a iterator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I don't know why there is no display to screen with the **number one**.
The iterator is equal to one, and 1 is > that 0.
Please Explain it to me.

```
int main()
{
   bool hola;
   vector<bool> v;
   vector<bool>:: iterator it = v.begin();
   v.push_back (hola);
   cout << "numero tamano: " << int(v.size()) << endl;
   int i = int(v.size());
   if(i>0)
   }
      cout << *it << " this";
   }

   cout << "fin\n";

   return 0;
}
```

it only  output by screen is this:

```
numero tamano: 1
```

Comment: Element Insertions invalidate iterators.

Comment: Don't cast `v.size()` to `int` unnecessarily. The result of the `size()` function has type `size_t`, use that instead, or `auto` if you can use C++11 or later..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initialize your iterator before your push back.
That way your iterator is pointing to somewhere you don't have access
Thats why you get a segmentation
You will have to initialize the iterator after pushback. It will work fine.

```
bool hola;
vector<bool> v;
v.push_back (hola);
vector<bool>:: iterator it = v.begin();
cout << "numero tamano: " << int(v.size()) << endl;
int i = int(v.size());
while(it!=v.end())
{
    cout << *it << " this";
    it++;
}
```

Comment: Technically, OP didn't say that he was getting a segmentation fault. And, in general, it is not guaranteed that you will get one - it's undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You save an iterator in the line

```
vector<bool>:: iterator it = v.begin();
```

Then you perform an operation that (potentially (probably)) invalidates iterators (may not if you had previously called `.reserve` - but you didn't)

```
   v.push_back (hola);
```

Then you use the stored (now potentially (probably) invalid) iterator

```
  cout << *it << " this";
```

Don't do that.
Accessing an invalidated iterator is Undefined Behaviour and your entire program now has no meaning.

Comment: Technically, his iterator is invalidated regardless. As described [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) _Otherwise only the past-the-end iterator is invalidated._, and since he called [begin](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin) on an empty `std::vector`, it will be equal to `end` (_If the container is empty, the returned iterator will be equal to end()._).

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius Yes, I *know* that. I was just trying to put it in plain terms, rather than get all language-lawyer about it (which I tend to and which ppl tend to react badly to)..